# best way to add multiple cities option to a website

Tags: php, filter, dns, web, city

Say I want to develop a website that is city based, much like kijiji or craigslist.  What would be the best method to go on about adding multiple cities to it?  Sub domains, filters, specific pages..etc?  What do you think is the best approach for this?

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use city-based filtering like http://example.com/city_name
If you want to make subdomain based on city you can do that also using wildcard domain entry

Subdomain is best, if you can do that :)

Comment: Perfect. I think I know where to go from here now.  Thanks.